# AirPlay Screen Mirroring in IOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios11, airplay, ios12

I want to apply screen mirroring through code.In `iOS 11` and below we can achieve this task with `MPVolumeView` class

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html

In `iOS11` and later `iOS` The above class does not work for Screen Mirroring as it's only works for *Audio  mirroring* (**Airplay2**).

I also try `AVRoutePickerView`, but it is also working for audio mirroring only((**Airplay2**)).

In simple through code I want the same result with we can achieve with "Control Centre" "Screen Mirroring" button.check  below video (1min 18secs in) for "Screen Mirroring" exact location.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=80&v=wbWXNESUZ5w

Please check the attach image for exact location of screen mirroring button[image]

Thanks

Comment: I am also looking for that :-/

Comment: Did you get any workaround ?